# Supported GPU for Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, gpu

## Question

Which GPUs are supported in Pytorch and where is the information located?

### Background

Almost all articles of Pytorch + GPU are about NVIDIA. Is NVIDIA the only GPU that can be used by Pytorch? If not, which GPUs are usable and where I can find the information?

Comment: This github issue https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/488 has some nice explanation why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, you need a NVIDIA GPU compatible with CUDA 8, 9 or 10: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

NVIDIA has a list of compatible cards here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute

Alternatively you could work on a GPU equipped [cloud instance](https://pytorch.org/get-started/cloud-partners/) (or install pytorch without GPU).

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: haven't tried this myself, but last year AMD announced ROCm 5.7 support for Pytorch on a couple of their graphics cards running Ubuntu: https://pytorch.org/blog/amd-extends-support-for-pt-ml/

"Researchers and developers working with Machine Learning (ML) models and algorithms using PyTorch can now use AMD ROCm 5.7 on Ubuntu® Linux® to tap into the parallel computing power of the Radeon™ RX 7900 XTX and the Radeon™ PRO W7900 graphics cards which are based on the AMD RDNA™ 3 GPU architecture."

Given that their Radeon 7900 XTX 24GB cards are about 1K cheaper than an RTX4090, would be great to hear how well these work in practice.